# how to send value of button input as value of different input type

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have the following button input and need to make it as a trigger to different input type as it's clicked.

```
<input type="button" name="submit item" value="Submit Item"/>



<c:set var="totalX" value="0"></c:set>
<s:set var="j" value="0"></s:set>
<display:table name="${listQuoteItem }" id="g" pagesize="1000" excludedParams="*" style="width: 100%;" class="style1">
<display:column title="@item" style="text-center">                  
<input style="width:95%;text-align: right" type="text" name="listQuote[${g_rowNum-1 }].itemTotal" id="dataTotal${g_rowNum-1 }" readonly="readonly" value="${g.itemTotal}"/>
</display:column>

<s:set var="j" value="#j+1"></s:set>                    
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change code like that:

```
<input type="button" name="submit item" value="Submit Item" onclick="myfunction()"/>
```

And into my function trigger other input button

```
myfunction(){
enter code here code to trigger other button
}
```

Comment: what i need is once user click button, it will trigger value of input text. How can i do that?

Comment: @DoniAndriCahyono what it mean it will trigger value of input text.??

Comment: 1. user click button
2. input text value will be changed according to no. 1

Answer (score 0):

To add events on clicking a button use **onclick** method.
Syntax is onlick="function-name(arg1,arg2)".
Then define a javascript function and do what you want to do.

Example:

```
<input type="button" name="submit item" value="Submit Item" onclick="alertBox()"/>

alertBox(){    
  alert("This is an alert");
  // you can define anything else also that you want to do.
}
```